# Allocating the timeframe based on the datetime using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I need to find the timeframe from the master based on the input time.
cust_id             starttime
0        1  2000-01-01 09:00:03
1        2  2000-01-01 18:01:03

output i needed is
cust_id             starttime    timeframe
0        1  2000-01-01 09:00:03   morning
1        2  2000-01-01 18:01:03   evening

Code for creating master timeframe details
mastdf={'timeframe':['morning','latemorning','midnoon','evening'],'start_time':['8:00:00','11:00:00','13:00:00','17:00:00'],'end_time':['10:59:59','13:59:59','16:59:59','7:59:59']}

Code for creating input dataframe
inputdf={'cust_id':[1,2],'starttime':['2000-01-01 09:00:03', '2000-01-01 18:01:03']}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for binning but first convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), create bins with add endpoint `24H` and for timeframe between `00:00:00` to `8:00:00` is used `fillna` by last value of column `timeframe`:

```
mastdf={'timeframe':['morning','latemorning','midnoon','evening'],
        'start_time':['8:00:00','11:00:00','13:00:00','17:00:00'],
        'end_time':['10:59:59','13:59:59','16:59:59','7:59:59']}
mastdf = pd.DataFrame(mastdf)
print (mastdf)
     timeframe start_time  end_time
0      morning    8:00:00  10:59:59
1  latemorning   11:00:00  13:59:59
2      midnoon   13:00:00  16:59:59
3      evening   17:00:00   7:59:59

inputdf={'cust_id':[1,2],'starttime':['2000-01-01 09:00:03', '2000-01-01 18:01:03']}
inputdf = pd.DataFrame(inputdf)
inputdf['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(inputdf['starttime'])

start =  pd.to_timedelta(mastdf['start_time']).tolist() + [pd.Timedelta(24, unit='h')]
s = pd.to_timedelta(inputdf['starttime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
last = mastdf['timeframe'].iat[-1]
inputdf['timeframe'] = pd.cut(s, 
                              bins=start, 
                              labels=mastdf['timeframe'], right=False).fillna(last)
print (inputdf)
   cust_id           starttime timeframe
0        1 2000-01-01 09:00:03   morning
1        2 2000-01-01 18:01:03   evening
```